# Looping through multiple lists in parallel and temporarily looping through only one list

Tags: python, iteration

TL;DR: I'm trying to write a FIFO method calculator for accounting purposes, which iterates through two lists simultaneously (where each list is a collection of buy orders or sell orders, and each element of each list represents an individual order).

In Python, is there a way to loop through two sequenced data structures (let's say two lists) in parallel, but then to also have some sort of condition where, if the condition is met, the program does a single iteration through one list and not the other, and then only if a different condition is met on the next iteration, looks at the lists in parallel once more?
For example, let's say we've got the two lists

```
list_1 = [25, 10, 1]

list_2 = [30, 15, 3]
```

Of course, we could initiate a for loop and use the zip() function in order to do a sequenced iteration through each list's element, in parallel, like so:

```
for one, two in zip(list_1, list_2):
```

And this would look at each element from both lists at the same time, in sequence, but it wouldn't work for the kind of condition I need to test.
I need to iterate through both list's elements at the same time, and then (I'm gonna just type the rest in plain English since I'm on a phone)...

if the value of the element of list_2 is greater than or equal to the value of the element of list_1,

then subtract the value of the element of list_2 and the value of the element of list_1, and then do something cool (this part isn't important for my question).

So... 30 - 25 = 5
...and then something cool is done.

But here's where it gets tricky for me.
At this point, the loop starts again and thus, the second iteration begins. The for loop initiated earlier would now be focused on the second elements for both lists, but what I want to do is basically pause the parallel loop and diverge. I want to look at the next element of list_1, but not the next element of list_2.
I need to take the remaining value from the last calculation (in this case, 5) and use that as the value of the element of list_2, during the this second iteration when it tests the condition again.

Of course, the condition stated earlier won't be met (5 is not greater than or equal to 10), and a different calculation is done as a result. Let's say...

subtract the element of list_1 and 5 and then do something cool.

So... 10 - 5 = 5
...and then something cool is done.

Now that the remainder from the first calculation has been dealt with, we can now use the "true" second element from list_2 for the next iteration.
However, since we have another remainder, we again need to pause the parallel loop and diverge for the next iteration.
This time, taking the remaining value from the last calculation (which would again be, 5) and use that as the value of the element of list_1, during this third iteration when it tests the condition again.

So... 15 - 5 = 10
...do something cool.

And the process repeats, but the loop needs to work on parallel (I think) in order to compare each list's element and I'm completely stumped on how to go about making this work in the way I've described.

Comment: Have you tried recursion?

Comment: Keep two pointers, i, and j, and advance them accordingly inside a while loop... You can probably figure out the rest.

Comment: Not sure how recursion would apply, also not too sure how to iterate through both lists simultaneously in a while loop but then pause and only iterate through one list the way I need to. I'm new to programming and just started teaching myself Python so if you could be a bit more specific I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

> what I want to do is basically pause the parallel loop and diverge

Then do so. Use `enumerate` to access the loop index and grab the appropriate slice of the list.

```
for i, (one, two) in enumerate(zip(list_1, list_2)):
    for three in list_1[i:]:
        # loop through list_1
    # return to previous pair position
```

> I want to look at the next element of list_1, but not the next element of list_2

Again, access the loop index with `enumerate`. You can grab any arbitrary element within the list's bounds.

```
for i (one) in enumerate(list_1):
    do_something(one)         # i-th item
    do_something(list_1[i+1]) # (i+1)-th item
    do_something(list_1[i+1]) # (i+n)-th item
```

> I need to take the remaining value from the last calculation ...

Then save it. If only the result of some calculation is required at every next iteration, you'll want to do the first such calculation before you begin the loop, so that the result of the (i-1)-th iteration is always available to the i-th iteration. Note how the loop starts at the second pair of items.

```
result = list_2[0] - list[0]
do_something(result)
for i, (one, two) in enumerate(zip(list_1[1:], list_2[1:])):
    if result >= one:
        result = result - one
        do_something(result)
    if two >= one:
        result = two - one
        do_something(result)
```

If you only ever need the next element you might compute all the parallel differences in advance so that you have access to all the previous pair results at each iteration.

```
list_3 = [two - one for one,two in zip(list_1,list_2)]
for one, two, three in zip(list_1, list_2, list_3):
    # three == two - one
    # maybe do something based on sign of three
```

Alternatively you might operate on a sort of region at each iteration.

```
for a, aa, b, bb in zip(list_1, list_1[1:], list_2, list_2[1:]):
    do_something(aa-b-a)
    do_something(bb-b-a)
    do_something(b-a)
```